# When I run this page I see error in firebug

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting fire bug $("project").autocomplete is not function.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $(function() {        
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                url : "<?php base_url() ?>stud_data",
                success: function(data) {
                    projects = data.value;                
                }  

            });
            $( '#project' ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: projects,
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( '#project' ).val( ui.item.label );
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( '#project' ).val( ui.item.label );
                    $( '#project-id' ).val( ui.item.value );
                    $( '#project-description' ).html( ui.item.desc );
                    $( '#project-icon' ).attr( "src", ui.item.icon );           
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a> <b>" + item.label +"</b>" + item.photo +"<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };
        });
    });
 </script>
```

**Edit:**

```
<script src="<? base_url() ?>/js/jqueryui/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? base_url() ?>/js/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? base_url() ?>/js/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? base_url() ?>/js/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css">

<script src="<? base_url() ?>/js/jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<? base_url() ?>/js/jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<? base_url() ?>/js/jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<? base_url() ?>/js/jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/source/core/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<? base_url() ?>/js/jquery_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? base_url() ?>/js/jquery_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: did you include the plugin in your page?

Comment: Make sure you are including the jquery ui javascript file http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: i have included all plugins please see it in my edit.

Comment: i think one among **$(document).ready(function (){** or **$(function(){** is enough. Dont use both. :)

Answer (score 4):

Open Firbug and Enable **NET** and see the all js and make sure that no file status is **404**

Second Debug your Ajax request , if not just  modify code the

```
<? base_url() ?> to <?=base_url() ?>
```

Same thing in your Ajax code

```
$.ajax({
   //Your code
   url : "<?php echo base_url() ?>stud_data",
})
```

remove `$(function() {  })` from your code because you already use `$(document).read(function(){ })` both are doing same thing

Hope it help